# Creating an MPI_Datatype for a structure containing pointers

Tags: c, mpi

I have the following structure.

```
typedef struct
{
 int *Ai;
 double *Ax;
 int nz;
}column;
```

I want to transfer this structure using `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Receive`. How do I create an `MPI_Datatype` for this structure?

Comment: Why would you ever want to send pointers between MPI processes? They are non-portable in distributed memory systems.

Answer (score 12):

MPI is designed to work with arrays of structures rather that with structures of arrays.

The `MPI_Hindexed` that @suszterpatt proposed is a terrible hack. It will only allow you to send one element of the structure type and only the element that was used to define the MPI data type. For other variables of the same structure type it is mostly guaranteed that the computed offsets will be wrong. Besides **Hindexed** types use one and the same MPI data type for all elements and thus does not allow you to send both ints and doubles.

The wise thing to do is to transform your program to use arrays of structures:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    int i;
    double z;
 } point;

 typedef struct
 {
    point *A;
    int nz;
 } column;
```

Now you can create an MPI structured type `point_type` and use it to send `nz` elements of that type giving `column.A` as the buffer address:

```
 int lens[3];
 MPI_Aint base, disps[2];
 MPI_Datatype oldtypes[2], point_struct, point_type;

 MPI_Get_address(&point, disps);
 MPI_Get_address(&point.z, disps+1);
 base = disps[0];

 lens[0] = 1; disps[0] = MPI_Aint_diff(disps[0], base); oldtypes[0] = MPI_INT;
 lens[1] = 1; disps[1] = MPI_Aint_diff(disps[1], base); oldtypes[1] = MPI_DOUBLE;
 MPI_Type_create_struct(2, lens, disps, oldtypes, &point_struct);
 MPI_Type_create_resized(point_struct, 0, sizeof(point), &point_type);
 MPI_Type_commit(&point_type);

 MPI_Send(column.A, column.nz, point_type, ...);
```

This first creates an MPI datatype `point_struct` that describes the layout of the structure members, but does not account for any padding at the end and therefore cannot be used to reliably send an array of such structures. Therefore, a second datatype `point_type` with the correct extent is created using `MPI_Type_create_resized`.

On the receiver side you would peek the message with `MPI_Probe`, extract the number of elements with `MPI_Get_count` with a type of `point_type` (that goes straight to the `nz` field), allocate the `A` field and use it in `MPI_Recv` to receive the `nz` elements:

```
 MPI_Status status;
 MPI_Probe(source, tag, comm, &status);
 MPI_Get_count(&status, point_type, &column.nz);
 if (nz == MPI_UNDEFINED)
   ... non-integral message was received, do something
 column.A = (point *)malloc(column.nz*sizeof(point));
 MPI_Recv(column.A, column.nz, point_type, source, tag, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

If that code change is impossible you can still go through the intermediate step of transforming your structure before sending it, a process usually called *(un-)marshaling*. In your case do something like this (I assume that you store the number of array elements in both `Ai` and `Ax` in the `nz` field):

```
 point *temp = (point *)malloc(nz*sizeof(point));
 for (int i = 0; i < column.nz; i++)
 {
   temp[i].i = column.Ai[i];
   temp[i].z = column.Az[i];
 }
 MPI_Send(temp, nz, point_type, ...);
 free(temp);
```

On the receiver side you must do the opposite: allocate a large enough buffer that can hold the structure, receive the message in it and then do the opposite transformation.

Once again, you do not need to transmit the actual value of `nz` since it can be easily extracted from the length of the message using `MPI_Get_count`.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I used an intermediate representation like you suggested and it was much better.

Comment: Are you sure about the "disp[0]"? If the zero element is a character I wouldn't know whether it was in the left or right byte of the smallest alignment unit. In other words: I would compute its offset explicitly.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, the C standard (specifically ISO/IEC 9899:1999, haven't read the older documents) mandates that a pointer to a structure is a pointer to its first member, therefore the offset of the first member if computed likewise will be zero; padding at the beginning of a structure is not allowed (§6.7.2.1(13)). But the code is terrible anyway - pointer arithmetic with different pointer types and use of `MPI_UB`...

Answer (score 8):

Sending pointers to another machine is pointless (no pun intended). Due to virtual addressing, the pointer will likely point to an invalid memory location on the receiving machine, and even if not, you haven't actually sent the data that it was pointing to.

However, with proper use of `MPI_Address()` and an `MPI_Hindexed` datatype, it is possible to describe the memory layout of your data (I'm assuming that your pointers point to dynamic arrays). E.g. if `Ai` points to 3 `int`s, and `Ax` points to 5 `double`s, you'll need a `Hindexed` type with 3 blocks: 3 `MPI_INT`s, 5 `MPI_DOUBLE`s, and 1 `MPI_INT`, with the offsets acquired using `MPI_Address()`.

Don't forget to redefine and recommit the datatype if you change the number of items to be sent or reallocate the arrays entirely. And if you're sending multiple structs, you'll have to define and commit this datatype for each one, since your MPI datatype is specific to one particular instance of these structs.

Also keep in mind that you'll have to do some similarly tricky unpacking on the receiving end if you want to recreate the original struct.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it was a round about way and was creating too many datatypes. So I changed my data representation instead. Yes the pointers were to dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 3):

"The wise thing to do is to transform your program to use arrays of structures"

Often that's conceptually also better.

I would like to point out another mechanism: using MPI_Pack and MPI_Unpack. For instance, with the original structure you could pack the first integer, then pack the two arrays. The receiver would unpack the integer and then know how many of the other thingies to unpack.

This is also a good solution if your object is not directly accessible but can only be accessed through an iterator or so.