# send/receive object arrays using MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Is it possible to send/receive C++ object and object arrays using MPI_Bcast, MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather. If yes then which MPI datatype is used for objects?
For example I have a class named cell.

```
class cell
{
private:        
  int abc;
  double xyz;

public:
    cell(){ }                
     ...
};
```

In the main function, I would like to make an object array of class cell and would like to send/receive as object array. e.g.,

```
void main ()
{
...
    cell** cells = new cell*[someVar];
        for(int i = 0; i < someVar; ++i) 
        {
            cells[i] = new cell[someVar];
        }
MPI_Bcast(cells, someVar, ???, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
...
}
```

How can we define an MPI data type to send / receive an object array?

Comment: You need to specify what language you're working in, and what exactly you mean by 'object'. That could be anything from arbitrary primitive types in C, to C++ classes containing arbitrary data structures. In general, though, to send something that doesn't have a pre-defined MPI datatype (e.g. MPI_INT), you must construct the appropriate datatype yourself, by enumerating its primitive elements.

Comment: @Novelocrat how to construct a datatype for C++ objects?

Comment: I think that the second answer to this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419990/creating-an-mpi-datatype-for-a-structure-containing-pointers -- will be of interest and use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MPI_Pack / MPI_Unpack mechanism. On the sending side you stuff the elements into a pack buffer and you send that; the receiving side unpacks it component-by-component. This offers such cute possibilities as first unpacking an integer that tells you how many subsequent doubles there are to unpack. A big advantage of this approach is that it applies to objects that are only indirectly accessible through an iterator or such.