# MPI with derived data types in Fortran 90. Broadcast trouble

Tags: types, fortran, mpi

I am stuck since a while with a Fortran 90 code that uses modules, derived data types and MPI.

The problem I have is that after broadcasting the derived data types, only the variables of the master node have the correct values, the variables on all other nodes don't contain what they should. I abstracted a minimal example from our larger code. It contains the main program:

---

```
include 'hello_types.f90'
include 'mpi_circle.f90'

program hello_world

use type_hello_world
use create_mpi_types

implicit none

include 'mpif.h'

integer         :: ierr, num_procs, my_id, mesg_mpi_circle
type(circle_)       :: circle

call MPI_Init(ierr)

!find out MY process ID, and how many processes were started.

call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)

allocate(circle%diameter(3),circle%straal(3))

if (my_id==0) then
print*,'enter straal and diameter'
read*,circle%diameter(1),circle%straal(1)
circle%diameter(2)=circle%diameter(1)
circle%straal(2)=circle%straal(1)
endif

call build_derived_circle(circle,mesg_mpi_circle)

call MPI_BCAST(circle,1,mesg_mpi_circle,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)


print *, "Hello world! I'm process ", my_id, " out of", num_procs, " processes."
print*,my_id,mesg_mpi_circle%diameter(my_id+1),mesg_mpi_circle%straal(my_id+1)

call MPI_Finalize(ierr)


end program hello_world
```

---

The output contains two print statements, where the first one just prints the proc_id (which works fine) and the second prints out the variables on the respective node (This is where i have the problem, only on the master node the values are fine). The variables come via read in on the master node.

Further there is a module where the type is defined:

---

```
module type_hello_world

type circle_
   real,allocatable  :: straal(:),diameter(:)
end type circle_

end module type_hello_world
```

---

As I said, I abstracted this from a larger code, so this module may seems useless but makes sense in the original code.

And as third a module that contains a subroutine to calculate displacements for the broadcast of derived data types .....
I followed the MPI Users guide for Fortran from http://ladon.iqfr.csic.es/docs/MPI_ug_in_FORTRAN.pdf

---

```
module create_mpi_types

contains

subroutine build_derived_circle(circle,mesg_mpi_circle)

use type_hello_world

implicit none


include 'mpif.h'


type(circle_),intent(in)     :: circle

! local
integer,parameter       :: number=2
integer                 :: ierr, i
integer             :: block_lengths(number)
integer                 :: displacements(number)
integer                 :: address(number+1)
integer                 :: typelist(number)


!output
integer,intent(out) :: mesg_mpi_circle

!----------------------------------------

!  first specify the types
typelist(1)=MPI_REAL
typelist(2)=MPI_REAL

! specify the number of elements of each type
block_lengths(1)=size(circle%straal)
block_lengths(2)=size(circle%diameter)

! calculate displacements relative to refr. 
call MPI_Address(circle,address(1),ierr)
call MPI_Address(circle%straal,address(2),ierr)
call MPI_Address(circle%diameter,address(3),ierr)

do i = 1, number
    displacements(i)=address(i+1)-address(i)
enddo

! build the derived data type
call MPI_TYPE_STRUCT(number,block_lengths,displacements,&
                    typelist,mesg_mpi_circle,ierr)
! commit it to the system, so it knows we ll use it 
! for communication
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(mesg_mpi_circle,ierr)

return

end subroutine build_derived_circle

!------------- END SUBROUTINE----------------------------
end module create_mpi_types
```

---

For the setup: The code is intended to run on the ETH Brutus cluster under CentOs6 compiled with Intel fortran. However we tested it on some machines getting the same problem, so I don't think it is a version problem.

Comment: A tip: don't `include "mpif.h"` but `use mpi`. It can help you to find some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a version problem. The short answer is MPI does not like types with allocatable arrays. This is the same as [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419990/creating-an-mpi-datatype-for-a-structure-containing-pointers). It has to do with pointers and virtual memory addresses, the cited answer shows you how to do it if you really wanted. However if possible I would do it by method number 2 outlined below.

There are two possible ways of doing this.
1) Create fixed length arrays within `type_hello_world`

```
type circle_
   real :: straal(100)
   real :: diameter(100)
end type circle_
```

2) Create a type of `circle` with only one element, then create an array of circles.

```
type circle_
   real :: straal
   real :: diameter
end type circle_
```

I prefer the second method. Note also that the displacements should be of type MPI_ADDRESS_KIND. So your code would change for `create_mpi_types` to

```
module create_mpi_types

contains

subroutine build_derived_circle(mesg_mpi_circle)

use type_hello_world
use mpi

implicit none


! local
type(circle_)                  :: circle
integer,parameter              :: number=2
integer                        :: ierr, i
integer                        :: block_lengths(number)
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: displacements(number)
integer                        :: typelist(number)
real                           :: r

!output
integer,intent(out) :: mesg_mpi_circle

!----------------------------------------

do i = 0, number
    typelist(i) = MPI_REAL
    block_lengths(i) = 1
    displacements(i) = i * sizeof(r)
enddo
! build the derived data type
call MPI_Type_create_struct(number,block_lengths,displacements,&
                typelist,mesg_mpi_circle,ierr)
if (ierr /= 0 ) then
    print *, 'got an error in type create: ', ierr
    call MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr, ierr)
endif

! commit it to the system, so it knows we ll use it
! for communication
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(mesg_mpi_circle,ierr)
if (ierr /= 0 ) then
    print *, 'got an error in type commit: ', ierr
    call MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr, ierr)
endif

return

end subroutine build_derived_circle

!------------- END SUBROUTINE----------------------------
end module create_mpi_types
```

And then to use it in `hello_world`

```
include 'hello_types.f90'
include 'mpi_circle.f90'

program hello_world

use mpi
use type_hello_world
use create_mpi_types

implicit none

integer                    :: ierr, num_procs, my_id, mpi_circle_t
type(circle_), allocatable :: circles(:)

call MPI_Init(ierr)

!find out MY process ID, and how many processes were started.

call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)

allocate(circles(num_procs))

if (my_id==0) then
    !print*,'enter straal and diameter'
    !read*,circle%diameter(1),circle%straal(1)
    circles(:)%diameter = 10.0
    circles(:)%straal = 2.0
endif

call build_derived_circle(mpi_circle_t)

call MPI_BCAST(circles,num_procs,mpi_circle_t,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

print *, "Hello world! I'm process ", my_id, " out of", num_procs, " processes."
print*,my_id,circles(my_id+1)%diameter,circles(my_id+1)%straal

call MPI_TYPE_FREE(mpi_circle_t, ierr)
deallocate(circles)

call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
```