# FORTRAN and MPI: allocate and initialize array of user-defined type using input file

Tags: memory-management, file-io, parallel-processing, fortran

I have an allocatable array of a user-defined type. The size of the array and the values of the array elements should be read in from a file. I have a serial code which looks something like this:

```
MODULE read_and_allocate
  IMPLICIT NONE

  TYPE my_type
     INTEGER :: my_number
     CHARACTER(10) :: my_string

   CONTAINS
     PROCEDURE :: read_my_type_from_string_array
     PROCEDURE :: write_my_type
     GENERIC :: WRITE(formatted) => write_my_type
  END TYPE my_type

  TYPE(my_type), ALLOCATABLE :: my_array(:)

  CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE read_my_type_from_string_array(var, string_array)
      CLASS(my_type), INTENT(INOUT) :: var
      CHARACTER(*), INTENT(IN) :: string_array(:)

       !code omitted
    END SUBROUTINE read_my_type_from_string_array


    SUBROUTINE write_my_type(var, funit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
       !code omitted
    END SUBROUTINE write_my_type


    SUBROUTINE read_my_array(var, funit)!, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
      TYPE(my_type), ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(INOUT) :: var(:)
      INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: funit

      CHARACTER(200) :: line
      INTEGER :: rec_count, rec_len, max_rec_len
      LOGICAL :: in_rec
      INTEGER :: pos
      CHARACTER(200),ALLOCATABLE :: rec(:)
      INTEGER :: ii, jj
      INTEGER :: status

      ! calling read_my_array deallocates var
      IF (ALLOCATED(var)) DEALLOCATE(var)

      max_rec_len = 0
      rec_count = 0
      in_rec = .FALSE.
      DO
         READ(funit, '(a)', iostat=status) line
         IF (status < 0) EXIT

         IF (in_rec .AND. TRIM(ADJUSTL(line)) == ']') THEN
            in_rec = .FALSE.
         END IF

         IF (in_rec) THEN
            rec_len = rec_len+1
         END IF


         IF (.NOT. in_rec .AND. TRIM(ADJUSTL(line)) == '[my_type') THEN
            in_rec = .TRUE.
            max_rec_len = MAX(max_rec_len, rec_len)
            rec_len = 0
            rec_count = rec_count + 1
         END IF
      END DO

      ALLOCATE(rec(max_rec_len))
      ALLOCATE(var(rec_count))
      REWIND(funit)

      in_rec = .FALSE.
      jj = 1
      DO
         READ(funit, '(a)', iostat=status) line
         IF (status < 0) EXIT

         IF (in_rec .AND. TRIM(ADJUSTL(line)) == ']') THEN
            CALL var(jj)%read_my_type_from_string_array(rec)
            jj = jj + 1
            in_rec = .FALSE.
         END IF

         IF (in_rec) THEN
            rec(ii) = line
            ii = ii+1
         END IF


         IF (.NOT. in_rec .AND. TRIM(ADJUSTL(line)) == '[my_type') THEN
            in_rec = .TRUE.
            rec(:) = ''
            ii = 1
         END IF
      END DO

      DEALLOCATE(rec)

    END SUBROUTINE read_my_array


    SUBROUTINE write_my_array(var, funit)
       !code omitted
    END SUBROUTINE write_my_array


END MODULE read_and_allocate

PROGRAM my_test

  USE read_and_allocate

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER :: funit

  OPEN(newunit=funit, file='input.txt')

  CALL read_my_array(my_array, funit) !this routine allocates my_array

  CALL write_my_array(my_array, 6)


END PROGRAM my_test
```

This works as expected (tested with gfortran on a mac). In short, `read_my_array` processes the given input file, infers the needed size (N) of `my_array`, allocates 'my_array', and then calls `read_my_type_from_string_array` N times to fill each element of `my_array` with data.

Now I want to port this code into an existing parallel program, but I'm not quite certain how to do this properly. I think I have two choices, but I have concerns about both of them:

1) I could read in the the text file only in the master process, but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15824192/2454357), I'm not sure if I can broadcast an allocatable array all that easily.

2) I could make each process read the text file separately, but I'm worried that I could create some kind of race condition (the function `read_my_array` uses `REWIND` and `BACKSPACE`), where different processes would get different results for `my_array`. I found [this Intel forum thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/270042) where the `SHARE` option is mentioned for file-opening -- I'm not quite sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Is there a best practice how to do these kind of things?

**EDIT**:

An example input file would look something like this:

```
[my_type
  my_string = 'one'
  my_number = 1
]
[my_type
  my_string = 'two'
  my_number = 4
]
[my_type
  my_string = 'alfred'
  my_number = 7
]
```

Comment: That depends mostly on the code omitted. You could be able to use MPI-IO.

Comment: @VladimirF I updated the question. I'm somewhat reluctant to post all the code, it's 170 lines long ...

Comment: Then I would just call the same reading procedure from all processes separately unless the data is huge (gigabytes). The Intel link is irrelevant, it is about threads, not processes.