# Sending linked list through MPI

Tags: list, types, linked-list, fortran, mpi

I have seen this question being asked many times, but didn't find an answer that could resolve my issue. I want to be able to send a linked list, in Fortran, to another process through MPI. I have done something similar where the derived data type in the linked list was as follows

```
type a
{
 integer :: varA
 type(a), pointer :: next=>null()
 real :: varB
}
```

The way I did this was to create an MPI datatype which contained all the varA values together, and receive it as an array of integers. Then do the same for varB.

What I am trying to do now is to create the linked list, and then pack all the varA and varB values together to form the MPI datatype. I give below the code that does this.

```
PROGRAM TEST

 USE MPI
 IMPLICIT NONE

 TYPE a
  INTEGER:: b
  REAL :: e
  TYPE(a), POINTER :: nextPacketInList => NULL()     
 END TYPE 

 TYPE PacketComm
    INTEGER :: numPacketsToComm  
    TYPE(a), POINTER :: PacketListHeadPtr => NULL()
    TYPE(a), POINTER :: PacketListTailPtr => NULL()
 END TYPE PacketComm

 TYPE(PacketComm), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: PacketCommArray
 INTEGER :: packPacketDataType !New data type 
 INTEGER :: ierr, size, rank, dest, ind
 integer :: b
 real :: e

 CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
 CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
 CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

 IF(.NOT. ALLOCATED(PacketCommArray)) THEN
   ALLOCATE(PacketCommArray(0:size-1), STAT=ierr)
   DO ind=0, size-1
     PacketCommArray(ind)%numPacketsToComm = 0
   END DO
 ENDIF

 b = 2
 e = 4
 dest = 1
 CALL addPacketToList(b, e, dest)

 b = 3
 e = 5
 dest = 1

 CALL addPacketToList(b, e, dest)

 dest = 1
 CALL packPacketList(dest)

 IF(rank == 0) THEN
  dest = 1
  CALL sendPacketList(dest)
 ELSE
  CALL recvPacketList()
 ENDIF

 CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

 CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE addPacketToList(b, e, rank)

 IMPLICIT NONE

 INTEGER :: b, rank, ierr
 REAL :: e
 TYPE(a), POINTER :: head

 IF(.NOT. ASSOCIATED(PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr)) THEN
   ALLOCATE(PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr, STAT=ierr)
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr%b = b
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr%e = e
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr%nextPacketInList => NULL()
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr => PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr
   PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm = PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm+1
 ELSE
   ALLOCATE(PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr%nextPacketInList, STAT=ierr)
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr =>      PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr%nextPacketInList
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr%b = b
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr%e = e
   PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListTailPtr%nextPacketInList => NULL()
   PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm = PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm+1
 ENDIF

END SUBROUTINE addPacketToList

SUBROUTINE packPacketList(rank)
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER :: rank
  INTEGER :: numListNodes
  INTEGER(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: listNodeAddr
  INTEGER(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: listNodeDispl
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: listNodeTypes
 INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: listNodeCount

 TYPE(a), POINTER :: head

 INTEGER :: numNode

 head => PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr

 numListNodes = PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm

 PRINT *, ' Number of nodes to allocate for rank ', rank , ' is ', numListNodes

 ALLOCATE(listNodeTypes(2*numListNodes), stat=ierr)
 ALLOCATE(listNodeCount(2*numListNodes), stat=ierr)

 DO numNode=1, 2*numListNodes, 2
   listNodeTypes(numNode) = MPI_INTEGER
   listNodeTypes(numNode+1) = MPI_REAL
 END DO

 DO numNode=1, 2*numListNodes, 2
   listNodeCount(numNode) = 1
   listNodeCount(numNode+1) = 1
 END DO

 ALLOCATE(listNodeAddr(2*numListNodes), stat=ierr)
 ALLOCATE(listNodeDispl(2*numListNodes), stat=ierr)

 numNode = 1

 DO WHILE(ASSOCIATED(head))
  CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(head%b, listNodeAddr(numNode), ierr)
  CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(head%e, listNodeAddr(numNode+1), ierr)
  numNode = numNode + 2
  head => head%nextPacketInList
 END DO

 DO numNode=1, UBOUND(listNodeAddr,1)
  listNodeDispl(numNode) = listNodeAddr(numNode) - listNodeAddr(1)
 END DO

 CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(UBOUND(listNodeAddr,1), listNodeCount, listNodeDispl,  listNodeTypes, packPacketDataType, ierr)

 CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(packPacketDataType, ierr)
END SUBROUTINE packPacketList

SUBROUTINE sendPacketList(rank)

 IMPLICIT NONE

 INTEGER :: rank, ierr, numNodes

 TYPE(a), POINTER :: head

 head => PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr

 numNodes = PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm

 CALL MPI_SSEND(head%b, 1, packPacketDataType, rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

END SUBROUTINE sendPacketList

SUBROUTINE recvPacketList

 IMPLICIT NONE

 TYPE(a), POINTER :: head

 TYPE(a), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: RecvPacketCommArray
 INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: recvB

 INTEGER :: numNodes, ierr, numNode
 INTEGER, DIMENSION(MPI_STATUS_SIZE):: status

 head => PacketCommArray(rank)%PacketListHeadPtr

 numNodes = PacketCommArray(rank)%numPacketsToComm

 ALLOCATE(RecvPacketCommArray(numNodes), stat=ierr)
 ALLOCATE(recvB(numNodes), stat=ierr)

 CALL MPI_RECV(RecvPacketCommArray, 1, packPacketDataType, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)

 DO numNode=1, numNodes
    PRINT *, ' value in b', RecvPacketCommArray(numNode)%b
    PRINT *, ' value in e', RecvPacketCommArray(numNode)%e
 END DO

END SUBROUTINE recvPacketList
END PROGRAM TEST
```

So basically I create a linked list with two nodes containing the following data

Node 1
   b = 2, e = 4

Node 2 
   b = 3, e = 5

When I run this code on two cores, the results I get on core 1 are

```
value in b           2
value in e   4.000000

value in b           0
value in e  0.0000000E+00
```

So my code seems to send the data in the first node of the linked list correctly, but not the second one. Please could someone let me know if what I am trying to do is feasible, and what is wrong with the code. I know I can send the values of b in all nodes together and then the values of e together. But my derived data type will probably contain more variables (including arrays) and I want to be able to send all the data in one go instead of using multiple sends.

Thanks

Comment: I saw this link that talks about something similar, where a poster asks to commit the data type for each instance of the struct. Could someone please elaborate on how this has to be done. Do I commit multiple times using an array of MPI data types?                                                            [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419990/creating-an-mpi-datatype-for-a-structure-containing-pointers)                                                           Also, how do I then calculate the displacements for the variable within each node of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy for me to read that code, but it seems like you are expecting the receiving buffer to get contiguous data, which is not the case. The strange type you construct by computing address offsets is not going to match the receiving buffer. To illustrate this, I though I might present this simple example (it's quickly written, don't take it as a good code example):

```
program example
use mpi

integer :: nprocs, myrank

integer :: buf(4)

integer :: n_elements
integer :: len_element(2)
integer(MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: disp_element(2)
integer :: type_element(2)
integer :: newtype
integer :: istat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
integer :: ierr

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, nprocs, ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, myrank, ierr)

! simple example illustrating mpi_type_create_struct
! take an integer array buf(4):
! on rank 0: [ 7, 2, 6, 4 ]
! on rank 1: [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
! and we create a struct to send only elements 1 and 3
! so that on rank 1 we'll get [7, 1, 6, 1]
if (myrank == 0) then
  buf = [7, 2, 6, 4]
else
  buf = 1
end if

n_elements = 2

len_element = 1
disp_element(1) = 0
disp_element(2) = 8
type_element = MPI_INTEGER
call mpi_type_create_struct(n_elements, len_element, disp_element, type_element, newtype, ierr)
call mpi_type_commit(newtype, ierr)

write(6,'(1x,a,i2,1x,a,4i2)') 'SEND| rank ', myrank, 'buf = ', buf

if (myrank == 0) then
  call mpi_send (buf, 1, newtype, 1, 13, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
else
  call mpi_recv (buf, 1, newtype, 0, 13, MPI_COMM_WORLD, istat, ierr)
  !the below call does not scatter the received integers, try to see the difference
  !call mpi_recv (buf, 2, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 13, MPI_COMM_WORLD, istat, ierr)
end if

write(6,'(1x,a,i2,1x,a,4i2)') 'RECV| rank ', myrank, 'buf = ', buf

end program
```

I hope this clearly shows that the receiving buffer will have to accommodate any offsets in the constructed type, and does not receive any contiguous data.

EDIT: updated the code to illustrate a different receive type that does not scatter the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, by non-contiguous data do you mean the data stored in the different nodes of the linked list? But the data within one node should be contiguous? I had done something similar earlier, but I was packing all the varA values together. Even in that case, the varA of different nodes are not stored in a contiguous way, and the use of MPI_Address was to get the displacements of each varA. So I am not sure why the example I provided above doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I could see, your trying to send sth like `[node1] ... [node2]` by constructing a new struct where the distance between the two nodes is computed by getting the memory addresses of the nodes, right? Then, your receiving buffer looks like `[node1][node2]`, a contiguous array of nodes, right? That can't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got the issue here. Instead of receiving it as a user defined data type, I need to receive it as a contiguous buffer of a single data type. I need to send all ints, real etc together instead of all the vars bunched up as a single datatype.

Comment: You can send scattered data by making a special type like you did. However, MPI will lump that data together and unpack it in the receive buffer according to the receiving type. Since your receiving type is also the special type, MPI will try to scatter the data in your receive buffer the same way it was in the send buffer (though it was not really scattered across a buffer, you kind of cheated). However, if the receiving type is a contiguous type, it will not scatter the values, I updated the example to illustrate this.

Comment: Last but not least, even if you would get it to work like this, the whole way you try to send the linked list is bad (in my opinion). You should pack your nodes before sending, then the send/recv becomes really easy (a contigous amount of node-sized types), then the receiving process should add the nodes to its list, or do whatever it wants to with them. So, if you have [1]->[2]->...[6] and you want to send [3] and [5], create an array to copy the two nodes two, send/recv the [3][5] array, unpack at the receiving end as you want.

Comment: Yes, and my way doesn't work either. I have now done it by packing together similar data types and unpacking them at the other end. Thanks for the help.