# Sending derived-type with allocatable array between MPI process

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi, allocation, derived-types

For the context, in my CFD simulation, my computational domain is divided in blocks. Each block has its own number of cells, each one containing various information. Blocks are distributed among processes through a domain decomposition algorithm to achieve a balanced load.

Meshing the computational domain is performed by process 0 only (I do not want to store the entire mesh in each process as it would be disastrous in term of memory used). Actually, the mesh is coded as a 1D array of blocks, each blocks being a complex derived type with allocatable statement of other derived-types:

```
TYPE something
    integer :: i,j,k
END TYPE something
!------
TYPE cell
    integer :: var1
    real, dimension(3) :: var2
    type(something), dimension(:), allocatable :: var3
END TYPE
!------
TYPE block
    integer :: var4
    real    :: var5
    type(cell), dimension(:), allocatable :: var6
END TYPE block
```

and the mesh defined as :

```
TYPE(block), dimension(n) :: mesh
```

My idea is then to use `MPI_SCATTERV` (each process handles a different amount of blocks) from process 0 to distribute chunks of my array `mesh` to other processes. At the end, I use a `MPI_GATHERV` to recover the entire domain if necessary. The problem is that I have to transfer complex derived-type.

I think I have to define MPI derived-type with `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT` since I have non-homogeneous data. I also read about `MPI_PACK` but it seems to be subject to memory overhead. Either way, I am stuck because I have to handle allocatable array inside each derived-type.

How can I define MPI derived-type with allocatable array? Of course, before sending data, those array are allocated but at compilation time, there are not. I need to use `MPI_GET_ADDRESS` to compute offsets between each data but I don't know how to do it with allocatable array. Do I need to switch to fixed-length arrays? Do I need to define each of the three types above and construct a 'super' MPI derived-type block? I was thinking about a loop over each cell of each block and send data one by one by that does not seem the right way to do it as it would require a huge number of mpi call, I am looking for a true 'block-block' communication.

Comment: You can't use a single derived type for all variables with an allocatable component. They will have the allocatable component stored at random addresses.

Comment: What about the `sequence` keyword to force storing array data contiguously in each type ?

Comment: That does not affect allocatable components in any way.

Comment: So there is no way to define a MPI derived type with allocatable components ? How then can I communicate with other processes ?

Comment: You past pack it yourself or send the component separately.

Comment: See also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419990/creating-an-mpi-datatype-for-a-structure-containing-pointers if you know C a little. Allocatable is just a special advanced type of pointer.